# Send dynamic data in the email for every new registration

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, custom, ce-1.9.1.1

I need to send some data in the email which is sent to every new registered user. The data is a string which is to be fetched from the database or an excel sheet(whichever is possible). I was wondering is there is anyway to do that.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to use Custom Variables.

- Navigate to **System > Custom Variables**

[image]

- Create your variable and give it values (HTML and plain text)

[image]

- Then navigate to **System > Transactional Emails**

[image]

- Under the **Load default template**, select the "New account" template and click <kbd>Load Template</kbd>.  Then use the <kbd>Insert Variable</kbd> button to locate and insert the variable you just created, and hit <kbd>Save</kbd>.

[image]

- Lastly, navigate to **System > Configuration**.  Under **Customer > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options**, select your new email template as the "Default Welcome Email" and click <kbd>Save</kbd>.

[image]

---

Otherwise for a more dynamic solution, you should create a custom block and template, then included it the transactional email template.

Comment: Thanks for the solution..but the data I need to put in the email is to be fetched from a database i.e. Dynamic..This is more of a static approach.